# jquery-mobile.js table adding table head twice on change of orientation

Tags: c#, jquery, html, jquery-mobile

I'm using jQuery Mobile.js to populate data from mysql, which when change of orientation adding table head twice for mobile view and when back to desktop view displaying opt table, am using this in my C# application.

my desktop view:

[image: my table view for desktop mode]

my mobile view:
[image: my mobile view]

my code:

```
if (_dtSales.Tables[0].Rows.Count > 0)
    {
        StringBuilder strHTMLContent = new StringBuilder();
        strHTMLContent.Append("<table data-role='table' id='movie-table'  border=1 border color=blue cellpadding=0 cellspacing=0 data-mode='reflow' class='ui-responsive table-stroke'>");
        strHTMLContent.Append("<thead>".ToString());
        strHTMLContent.Append("<tr>".ToString());
        strHTMLContent.Append("<th data-priority='1'>Date</th>".ToString());
        strHTMLContent.Append("<th data-priority='persist'>Agent</th>".ToString());
        strHTMLContent.Append("<th data-priority='2'>Product</th>".ToString());
        strHTMLContent.Append("<th data-priority='3'>Qty</th>".ToString());
        strHTMLContent.Append("<th data-priority='4'>Amount</th>".ToString());
        strHTMLContent.Append("<th data-priority='5'>Discount</th>".ToString());
        strHTMLContent.Append("<th data-priority='6'>After Discount</th>".ToString());

        strHTMLContent.Append(" </tr> ".ToString());
        strHTMLContent.Append("</thead>".ToString());
        strHTMLContent.Append("<tbody>".ToString());


        foreach (DataRow dr in _dtSales.Tables[0].Rows)
        {

            strHTMLContent.Append("<tr>".ToString());
            strHTMLContent.Append("<th>" + dr["date"].ToString() + "</th>".ToString());
            strHTMLContent.Append("<td>" + dr["agent_name"].ToString() + "</td>".ToString());
            strHTMLContent.Append("<td>" + dr["product_name"].ToString() + "</td>".ToString());
            strHTMLContent.Append("<td>" + dr["No_of_Qty"].ToString() + "</td>".ToString());
            strHTMLContent.Append("<td>" + dr["totalamount"].ToString() + "</td>".ToString());
            strHTMLContent.Append("<td>" + dr["discount"].ToString() + "</td>".ToString());
            strHTMLContent.Append("<td>" + dr["total_AfterDiscount"].ToString() + "</td>".ToString());
            strHTMLContent.Append(" </tr> ".ToString());
        }

        strHTMLContent.Append(" </tr> ".ToString());
        strHTMLContent.Append("</tbody>".ToString());

        strHTMLContent.Append("</table> ".ToString());
        view.InnerHtml = strHTMLContent.ToString();
    }
```

thanks in advance!!

Comment: where is the jquery code that applies the orientation?

Comment: @Übercoder am just switching between the desktop and mobile device to check the mobile.js table orientation alone not for the entire page